# Meteor/MongoDB pull data reactively

Tags: meteor

I have a method that checks for all unread messages belonging to a user. When the app loads, this number appears next to the "Messages" drop down. In Meteor, how would I update this count or variable for when a new message comes in or when the user reads an unread message? Pretty much I needs the method to send down the new count anytime a message status changes without refreshing the app itself.

I'm familiar with the [Tracker.autorun](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/tracker) functionality but I don't think it'll help with this situation. What's the best practice for approaching this?

Answer (score 0):

Use [Publish/Subscribe](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/publishandsubscribe). It is always reactive. If you do not want to have all unread messages sent to the client straight away and counted there, you create a custom collection that justs count the number of unread messages and publishes that count. Look at the example a bit down in the linked page that starts with

`// server: publish the current size of a collection`

This is exactly your use case.

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly this setup for new messages. In my header I have:

```
<li>Messages <span class="counter">{{Messages.count}}</span></li>
```

And then I have a helper that returns the cursor:

```
Template.header.helpers({
  Messages: function(){ return Messages.find(); }
});
```

In the old days, before David Weldon set me straight I used to have a helper to return the count, now I just refer to the count directly in the blaze html template.

Now, in this approach I'm subscribing to the `Messages` collection so that new messages are transmitted to the client and can then be counted locally. This is on the assumption that they are going to be read soon. If you want to avoid this step then you should probably publish a `Stats` collection or include a stats key in the user object so that just the count itself can be synced via pub-sub.

Answer (score 0):

You can just have a field like read, and update like:

Method for marking one message as read:

```
markRead: function(messageId){
    Messages.update(messageId, {
        $set: {
            read: true //this needs to be set to false when its inserted
        }
    })
}
```

Bulk update method (assuming all messages have receiverId saved):

```
markAllRead: function(){
    Messages.update({receiver: Meteor.userId(), read:false}, {
        $set: {
            read: true
        }
    }, {multi: true})
}
```

You can count `read:false` ones to retrieve count and you don't have to write anything else

Helper:

```
count: function(){
    //even if your publish/subscribe is correct, the count we want is from messages that are not read and the receiver is current user.
    return Messages.find({receiver: Meteor.userId(), read: false }).count();
}
```

Event:

```
'click .elementClass': function(){
    //both users see the messages and they can both click. We want to update the right message for the right user. Otherwise, the other user can mark the message as read when the receiver is the other user which they shouldn't be able to do. You can do a simple check on the client side, and another check in the method if necessary.
    if(this.receiver ===  Meteor.userId()){
        Meteor.call('markAsRead', this._id)
    }
}
```

Let me know if it solves your problem/answers all your questions.